# Initializing hard drive fails with Windows 10 or AOMEI Partition Assistant

Tags: hard-drive, format

I have a Toshiba 1TB 2.5" (MQ01ABD100) HDD I want to format and I don't care what is already on the disk, I just want it erased and functional.

- Windows 10 Disk Management: initialization (MBR or GPT) fails with message *"incorrect function"*, then all options on this disk are greyed out (*Initialize disk*, *New volume*, etc.).
- AOMEI Partition Assistant: initialization fails with message *"Failed to initialize this disk"*, while formatting to NTFS fails with *"Code 202: Failed to format NTFS due to too many bad clusters"*.

Finally, I quick scanned it with HD Tune and ALL sectors are seen as damaged *(all sectors? I don't think this is the reality)*. I think this disk was previously encrypted or something and I need to flash or crack whatever needs it.

---

Previous attempts were performed while the disk was connected via a USB adapter, with the new tests [below] performed with the disk connected directly via SATA.

- **`hdparm -I`:**

  ```bsh
  ATA device, with non-removable media

  Model Number:       TOSHIBA MQ01ABD100
  Serial Number:      xxxxxxxxx
  Firmware Revision:  AX1A1U

  Transport:          Serial, ATA8-AST, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6
  Standards:
  Supported:          8 7 6 5
  Likely used:        8

  Configuration:      Logical     max    current
  cylinders             16383   16383
  heads                    16      16
  sectors/track            63      63

  CHS current addressable sectors:    16514064
  LBA    user addressable sectors:   268435455
  LBA48  user addressable sectors:  1953525168

  Logical  Sector size:                   512 bytes
  Physical Sector size:                  4096 bytes
  Logical  Sector-0 offset:                 0 bytes

  device size with M = 1024*1024:      953869 MBytes
  device size with M = 1000*1000:     1000204 MBytes (1000 GB)
  cache/buffer size  = 8192 KBytes

  Form Factor:                        2.5 inch
  Nominal Media Rotation Rate:        5400
  Capabilities:                       LBA, IORDY(can be disabled)
  Queue depth:                        32

  Standby timer values:               specd by Standard, no device specific minimum
  R/W multiple sector transfer:       Max = 16 Current = 16
  Advanced power management level:    254

  DMA:                                sdma0 sdma1 sdma2 mdma0 mdma1 mdma2 udma0 udma1 udma2 udma3 udma4 *udma5
    Cycle time:                       min         = 120ns
                                      recommended = 120ns

  PIO:                                pio0 pio1 pio2 pio3 pio4
    Cycle time:                       no    flow control = 120ns
                                      IORDY flow control = 120ns

  Commands/features:
  Enabled Supported:
    * SMART feature set
    * Security Mode feature set
    * Power Management feature set
    * Write cache
    * Look-ahead
    * Host Protected Area feature set
    * WRITE_BUFFER command
    * READ_BUFFER command
    * NOP cmd
    * DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
    * Advanced Power Management feature set
      SET_MAX security extension
    * 48-bit Address feature set
    * Device Configuration Overlay feature set
    * Mandatory FLUSH_CACHE
    * FLUSH_CACHE_EXT
    * SMART error logging
    * SMART self-test
    * General Purpose Logging feature set
    * WRITE_{DMA|MULTIPLE}_FUA_EXT
    * 64-bit World wide name
    * IDLE_IMMEDIATE with UNLOAD
    * WRITE_UNCORRECTABLE_EXT command
    * {READ,WRITE}_DMA_EXT_GPL commands
    * Segmented DOWNLOAD_MICROCODE
    * Gen1 signaling speed (1.5Gb/s)
    * Gen2 signaling speed (3.0Gb/s)
    * Native Command Queueing (NCQ)
    * Host-initiated interface power management
    * Phy event counters
    * Idle-Unload when NCQ is active
    * DMA Setup Auto-Activate optimization
      Device-initiated interface power management
    * Software settings preservation
    * SMART Command Transport (SCT) feature set
    * SCT Write Same (AC2)
    * SCT Error Recovery Control (AC3)
    * SCT Features Control (AC4)
    * SCT Data Tables (AC5)

  Security:
    Master password revision code =     65534
    supported
    enabled
    locked
    not frozen
    not expired:                        security count
    supported:                          enhanced erase

    Security level maximum
    238min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT.
    238min for ENHANCED SECURITY ERASE UNIT.

    Logical Unit WWN Device Identifier: 5000039651b06f24
    NAA:                                5
    IEEE OUI:                           000039
    Unique ID:                          651b06f24
    Checksum:                           correct
  ```

  I see enabled and locked in the security part of the output; does this prevent me from using the disk?
- **`smartctl -t long`:**

  ```bsh
  === START OF OFFLINE IMMEDIATE AND SELF-TEST SECTION ===
  Sending command:  "Execute SMART Extended self-test routine immediately in off-line mode".
  Drive command     "Execute SMART Extended self-test routine immediately in off-line mode" successful.
  Testing has begun.
  Please wait 255 minutes for test to complete.
  Test will complete after Fri Dec 27 04:03:34 2019
  ```
- **`smartctl -a`:** (done a night after the previous long self-test)

  ```bsh
  === START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
  Model Family:     Toshiba 2.5 HDD MQ01ABD...
  Device Model:     TOSHIBA MQ01ABD100
  Serial Number:    xxxxxxxxx
  LU WWN Device Id: 5 000039 651b06f24
  Firmware Version: AX1A1U

  User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
  Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
  Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
  Form Factor:      2.5 inches

  Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
  ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
  SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 3.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)

  Local Time is:    Fri Dec 27 07:55:27 2019 UTC
  SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
  SMART support is: Enabled


  === START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
  SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

  General SMART Values:
  Offline data collection status:                 (0x00)  Offline data collection activity was never started.
    Auto Offline Data Collection:                 Disabled

  Self-test execution status:                     (   0)  The previous self-test routine completed without error or no self-test has ever been run.
  Total time to complete Offline data collection: (  120) seconds.

  Offline data collection capabilities:           (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
    Suspend Offline collection upon new
    command.
    Offline surface scan supported.
    Self-test supported.
    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
    Selective Self-test supported.

  SMART capabilities:                             (0x0003)    Saves SMART data before entering
    power-saving mode.
    Supports SMART auto save timer.

  Error logging capability:                       (0x01)  Error logging supported.
    General Purpose Logging supported.

  Short self-test routine polling time:           (   2) minutes.
  Extended self-test routine polling time:          ( 255) minutes.

  SCT capabilities:                               (0x003d)    SCT Status supported.
    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
    SCT Feature Control supported.
    SCT Data Table supported.

  SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16

  Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
  ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
    1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
    2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
    3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Always       -       2145
    4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       609
    5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       40
    7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
    8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
    9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   095   095   000    Old_age   Always       -       2052
   10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0033   112   100   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
   12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       347
  191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
  192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       26
  193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1173
  194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       28 (Min/Max 12/49)
  196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       4
  197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
  199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  220 Disk_Shift              0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  222 Loaded_Hours            0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       20
  223 Load_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  224 Load_Friction           0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  226 Load-in_Time            0x0026   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       258
  240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0001   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0

  SMART Error Log Version: 1
  ATA Error Count: 23 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]

  Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as:
  DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes, SS=sec, sss=millisec
  It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

  Error 23 occurred at disk power-on lifetime:      2043 hours (85 days + 3 hours)
    When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

    After command completion occurred, registers were:
    ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
    -- -- -- -- -- -- --
    04 51 00 00 00 00 40

    Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
    CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
    -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
    f2 00 01 00 00 00 40 00      00:16:02.988  SECURITY UNLOCK
    e5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00      00:15:59.882  CHECK POWER MODE
    e5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00      00:15:54.883  CHECK POWER MODE
    e5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00      00:15:49.885  CHECK POWER MODE
    f2 00 01 00 00 00 40 00      00:15:45.029  SECURITY UNLOCK


  Error 22 occurred at disk power-on lifetime:      2043 hours (85 days + 3 hours)
    When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

    After command completion occurred, registers were:
    ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
    -- -- -- -- -- -- --
    04 51 00 00 00 00 40

    Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
    CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
    -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
    f2 00 01 00 00 00 40 00      00:15:45.029  SECURITY UNLOCK
    e5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00      00:15:44.880  CHECK POWER MODE
    e5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00      00:15:39.885  CHECK POWER MODE
    e5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00      00:15:34.883  CHECK POWER MODE
    e5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00      00:15:29.882  CHECK POWER MODE


  Error 21 occurred at disk power-on lifetime:      2043 hours (85 days + 3 hours)
    When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

    After command completion occurred, registers were:
    ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
    -- -- -- -- -- -- --
    04 51 00 00 00 00 40

    Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
    CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
    -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
    f2 00 01 00 00 00 40 00      00:15:26.678  SECURITY UNLOCK
    e5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00      00:15:24.884  CHECK POWER MODE
    e5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00      00:15:19.881  CHECK POWER MODE
    e5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00      00:15:14.881  CHECK POWER MODE
    e5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00      00:15:09.885  CHECK POWER MODE


  Error 20 occurred at disk power-on lifetime:      2043 hours (85 days + 3 hours)
    When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

    After command completion occurred, registers were:
    ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
    -- -- -- -- -- -- --
    04 51 00 00 00 00 40

    Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
    CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
    -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
    f2 00 01 00 00 00 40 00      00:14:10.593  SECURITY UNLOCK
    e5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00      00:14:09.886  CHECK POWER MODE
    e5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00      00:14:04.886  CHECK POWER MODE
    e5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00      00:13:59.886  CHECK POWER MODE
    e5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00      00:13:54.886  CHECK POWER MODE


  Error 19 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 2043 hours (85 days + 3 hours)
    When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

    After command completion occurred, registers were:
    ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
    -- -- -- -- -- -- --
    04 51 00 00 00 00 40

    Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
    CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
    -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
    f2 00 01 00 00 00 40 00      00:10:19.977  SECURITY UNLOCK
    e5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00      00:10:19.886  CHECK POWER MODE
    e5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00      00:10:14.887  CHECK POWER MODE
    e5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00      00:10:09.886  CHECK POWER MODE
    e5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00      00:10:04.885  CHECK POWER MODE


  SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
  Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
  # 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      2047         -

  SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
   SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
      1        0        0  Not_testing
      2        0        0  Not_testing
      3        0        0  Not_testing
      4        0        0  Not_testing
      5        0        0  Not_testing

  Selective self-test flags (0x0):
    After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
  If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
  ```

I guess the hardware is fine?

Comment: Have you tried running a [GPartEd live image?](https://gparted.org/liveusb.php) I've often had more success doing my disk partitioning in there rather than on Windows.

Comment: @MMM That would be unwise since the drive's platters are damaged.  To verify, boot up a Linux LiveUSB, such as an Ubuntu Install USB, install `smartmontools`, then issue: `smartctl -a /dev/sda` (where `sda` is the drive in question - list drives via `ls /dev | grep sd`).   Scroll down in the output and there will likely be datestamps from when the drive suffered damage, then perform a long test on the drive via `smartctl -t long /dev/sda`

Comment: @MMM WHen I launch gparted, it's scanning the drive forever.

Comment: @JW0914 See my answers in the edit.

Comment: @Sephi The drive was dropped, or bumped hard enough to register enough G-forces, while powered on at least once (`191 G-Sense_Error_Rate  0x0032  100 
 100  000   Old_age  Always - 1`).  This caused damage to the platters to the extent of 23 hardware errors (`Error 23 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 2043 hours`).  The drive has only been powered on 85.5days (`9 Power_On_Hours  0x0032  095  095  000  Old_age  Always - 2052`) so it's still under warranty _(unless you had it sitting on a shelf for years)_ - I'd recommend filing for a warranty replacement (RA / RMA) on Toshiba's support site

Answer (score 2):

The hard drive has failed. If NTFS format says too may bad clusters (it did) then you cannot even use a portion of it. The drive is now unreliable and must be replaced.